# this.httpClientModule.get is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm just playing around with services in Angular for the first time and I get the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: this.httpClientModule.get is not a function

**my services file:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AlertsService {
    constructor(
        private httpClientModule: HttpClientModule
    ) {
        //
    }

    getAlerts() {
        console.warn(this.httpClientModule.get('api-data/alerts-data.json'));
    }
}
```

**component file:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertsService } from '../alerts.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'at-alerts',
    templateUrl: './alerts.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./alerts.component.scss'],
    providers: [AlertsService]
})

export class AlertsComponentEdit implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private alertsService: AlertsService
    ) {
        //
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.alertsService.getAlerts();
    }
}
```

**Mock data file (alerts-data.json):**

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Louis",
  "gender": "male"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Jenna",
  "gender": "female"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Tom",
  "gender": "male"
}];
```

From what I can tell `get` along with other methods like `post` etc should exist in `httpClientModule`, any idea how to resolve this error?

Comment: "playing around for the first time", maybe taking a look at the docs would be reasonable? https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing named get method inside **`httpClientModule`**.You need to inject **`HttpClient`** inside your constructor

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}     

getAlerts() {
    console.warn(this.http.get('api-data/alerts-data.json'));
}
```

Also import the **`HttpClientModule`** in your **`app.module.ts`**

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

so your app.module will look like,

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  declarations: [
  ],
  exports: [
  ]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```